# ASP.NET configuration for Parse.com backend

Tags: asp.net, parse-platform

I am trying to connect my ASP.NET website to a table in Parse.com. I have downloaded .NET 4.5 SDK and added to references in VS 2012. But now I dont know how can I reference my application to the backend table.

I think I should write somewhere like webconfig, application key or something like this so ASP.NET website can connect parse.com backend.

I searched for a tutorial but I couldnt find. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This quick start guide appears to have what you're looking for: https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart?onboard=#parse_data/desktop/windows/dot_net/existing

Comment: There is also a full example of connecting and working with data on github: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/TodoWindows

Comment: thanks. but these are win8 applications. My application is on ASP.NET which has no xaml file.

Comment: I believe the API will still be the same. Just look in the .cs files. I don't use Parse but that quick start guide and that sample project looked to show the basic principles.

Comment: you were right. .cs file enought to solve it. So what I did is just initialize the ParseClient

Comment: You should consider posting an answer with the relevant code since you have solved your problem =]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solution was simple. I just had to implement the code below in a .cs file.

```
ParseClient.Initialize("APPLICATION ID", ".NET KEY");

ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("TABLE"); 
gameScore["COL"] = "TEMP";
```

Comment: Are those keys meant to be secret?